# Trigger cloud function when new data in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I would like to trigger a Cloud Function when new data has been imported into a BigQuery table. Ideally, I would like to extract all the rows (one column is ISIN) that have been inserted.

Would this be possible and how?

Comment: Right now this is not possible, but stay tuned as there is something coming up soon.

Comment: In the mean time, would you suggest that the best solution for the moment is to have a cron job to check if the data is there and then trigger a background function using pubsub or http?

Comment: Create a job, and I would either list most recent jobs, and would push the jobid for further processing, or directly query the table for new rows.

Comment: You should be able to create pub/sub triggers from Stackdriver logs?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa yeah that's interesting aproach, turn on BQ audit logs, FWD Stackdriver logs to Pub/Sub, analyse there.

Comment: It has been a while now, you said stay tuned, is it possible now?

Comment: @Pentium10  news?

Comment: The “something coming soon” ... is that EventArc ( https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/build-event-driven-applications-in-cloud-run)?

Comment: Is there any way to filter the Path Pattern (my query is completed execution, I would like to add filter only for my query. We can see this query in jobCompletedEvent): I tried something like this in query window of log explorer-: 
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
protoPayload.methodName = "jobservice.jobcompleted"
protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.query.query like "%CALL %"
logName=("projects/Project/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access" )

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update June 2022: Cloud Functions 2nd Generation supports [Eventarc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/2nd-gen/overview#broader_event_coverage_and_cloudevents_support)**

Using Eventarc it's possible to listen to a long list of cloud events and then trigger a set of consumers including Cloud Functions.

The combination of `serviceName = bigquery.googleapis.com` and `methodName = jobservice.jobcompleted` with additional custom filters can be used to create the Eventrac sink, from which Cloud Functions can be triggered. You can read more [here](https://atamel.dev/posts/2021/06-08_bigquery-jobs-notifier/).

This is still not a native `BigQuery <> Cloud Function` integration, because it uses a 3rd cloud service. Therefore it's not much different than the solution suggested before June 2022 of creating a sink with Cloud Logging. Yet, this is the better practice these days of implementing cross-service triggers on GCP.

---

Old answer: Unfortunately BigQuery has no triggers as a native feature as of May 2022 :/ However there is a nice workaround you can implement! :)

As you probably know, almost every operation in GCP is logged to [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging) (previously StackDriver Logging). In [this](https://www.cardinalpath.com/blog/cloud-functions-bigquery-data-feed-automation) article they demonstrate how to trigger a Cloud Function whenever a BigQuery load job finishes. The idea is simple:

1. Create a filter for BigQuery load jobs in [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring#logs) to catch when load jobs terminate.
2. [Create a sink](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export#export_your_logs) from Cloud Logging to Pub/Sub topic.
3. [Set your Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) as a consumer on this topic and implement your logic

Google even published this concept as an [article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/how-trigger-cloud-run-actions-bigquery-events).

Comment: Agreed with this, already tried it before and it works great

Comment: Now Cloud Function 2nd gen, supports trigger based on BigQuery events

Comment: Is there any way to make the sink send the table's name/ID to PubSub using this method?