# Trigger dataflow job when new data arrived in Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have two BQ table A and B. What I want to achieve is when new data arrive in table A, a dataflow job can be triggered to transformed the new record and insert into table B, is this possible? If yes, is there any best practice?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are multiple ways of solving this problem. One way [derived from this stakoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792976/trigger-cloud-function-when-new-data-in-bigquery) is as follows:

1. Push **Stackdriver Logs** to **Pub/Sub** and apply a ***strong filter*** that only lets through logs of *BigQuery load jobs* into table A. Check out the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/design-patterns-for-exporting-stackdriver-logging#ways_to_export) for more information.
2. Create a [Cloud Function instance with a Pub/Sub trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#:%7E:text=Cloud%20Functions%20can%20be%20triggered,your%20own%20robust%2C%20global%20services).
3. The responsability of that function instance is to kickstart a **Dataflow Batch job**, which will carry out the necessary transformation before finally writing the resulting PCollection into table B.