# How to create a trigger for BigQuery on GCP and read the inserted value?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-run

I saw a few articles around (e.g. https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/how-trigger-cloud-run-actions-bigquery-events) that show how to create a "trigger" for BigQuery that activates Cloud Run (or a Cloud Function etc) using Cloud Logging to get notification that something has changed down to a BigQuery table. However how can I actually discover which values have been added to a table after an `insert`? For example if this happens on BQ:

`insert into mydataset.mytable (name, surname, age) values ('John','Smith',30)`

how can I discover from Cloud Run or a Cloud Function that the values `'John','Smith',30` have been actually added to the table `mydataset.mytable`?

Comment: you have the query in the log entry. Get the log entry, parse it, and you have the data.

Comment: you mean parsing `insert into...` to extract the part of string with the values?

Comment: Yes, exactly. There is no other option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger cloud function when new data in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792976/trigger-cloud-function-when-new-data-in-bigquery)

Comment: Not sure at this point, but seems that both solutions hit the same wall which is coupling your system with some custom code that can change at any time. I do not control the eventual BQ tables and even less the way that are built, so that queries can change at any time as the logs that I am checking do not return any other info apart from "sql query payload" as suggested by guillaume blaquiere above. Is passing through logs the only solution to extract "events" from BigQuery?