# Can't find BigQuery Logs for GA4 events_intraday tables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I am trying to create a trigger for a Cloud Function to copy events_intraday table data as soon as new data has been exported.
So far I have been following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792976/trigger-cloud-function-when-new-data-in-bigquery) answer to generate a sink from Cloud Logging to Pub/Sub.

I have only been able to find logs for events_YYYMMDD tables but none for events_intraday_YYYYMMDD neither on Cloud Logging nor on BigQuery Job History (Here are my queries for [events tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTqYp.png) and [events_intraday tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhk5O.png) on Cloud Logging).

Am I looking at the wrong place? How is it possible for the table to be updated without any logs being generated?

Update: There is one(1) log generated per day when the table is created but "table update" logs are yet to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
protoPayload.authorizationInfo.permission="bigquery.tables.create"
protoPayload.methodName="google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableService.InsertTable"
protoPayload.resourceName : "projects/'your_project'/datasets/'your_dataset'/tables/events_intraday_"
```

Comment: Hi @nik thanks for your answer! I had check "events_intraday_" tables' logs before. They only return one single log per day, when the table is created.