# Create Pub/Sub topic and send messages to it on BigQuery table updates

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a use case where I would like to run an on-demand scheduled query in Project A using a Cloud Function on updates to a BigQuery table (Table B) in another project, Project B. The table in Project B is roughly updated once every hour. I believe that the best way to do this would be to set up a Pub/Sub topic in Project B, and send a message to it on each and every update to the BigQuery table Table B, and then through a push subscription trigger the Cloud Function in Project A.

What I need help with is creating and configuring the Pub/Sub topic to be updated on every insert into Table B. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Very similar question, check out if that answer works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792976/trigger-cloud-function-when-new-data-in-bigquery

Comment: Use cloud logging, audit logs and Sink to PubSub feature. You can also have a look to eventarc

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @dnnshssm and @guillaume, you can either try triggering a Cloud Function for a specific event in BigQuery or leverage Cloud Logging - audit logs sink to Pub/Sub feature to ingest messages in Pub/Sub topic based on BigQuery logs.