# How to update view column in DatasetB from table column in DatasetA automate approach logic ? |bigquery|cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have a tableA in DatasetA

`DatasetA TableA`

| cd | xcd | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x1 | one |
| 2 | x2 |  |
| 3 | x3 | three |

And below is **viewA** created on **tableA** in **DatasetB** where value is empty

`DatasetB ViewA`

| cd | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |

How to automate the process of updating ***value*** in **viewA** which is in **DatasetB**  from ***value*** of **Dataset A Table A** ? If there is no data in value  , put some other value such as '*no value*'

```
**Expected Final Output of ViewA**
```

| cd | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one |
| 2 | no value |
| 3 | three |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is you can use [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/overview#functions) to automate your Bigquery update by attaching a Pub-Sub [Trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers#triggers), then create a [Cloud Scheduler Job](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub#create_a_job) that invokes the Pub/Sub trigger.

Another way to simply eliminate the need to use Cloud Function, Pub-Sub and Cloud Scheduler is to use the available tool in Bigquery - [SCHEDULE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) feature in your query editor:
[image]

Then create a new scheduled query:

[image]

You can use the following SQL query to update the view:

```sql
select viewA.cd,
if(tableA.value = '','no_value',tableA.value) as value
from `my-project.my_datasetA.my_table` as tableA
inner join `my-project.my_datasetB.my_view` as viewA
on cast(viewA.cd as string)  = tableA.cd;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Anjela B  for replying ! I wanted to check if there is any update made to value column of any table in project and it looks for view of the same name then it updates the value column of view. I tried using cloud function gen 2 to add an eventarc trigger `google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.PatchTable` thats gets triggered when an update is made in value column. But not sure how to capture it in a cloud function code.

Comment: You can't use `JobService.PatchTable` as trigger in cloud function since it is not supported. You can check the supported [methods for trigger](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/reference/supported-events#bigquery). You can check this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792976/trigger-cloud-function-when-new-data-in-bigquery for possible workaround. The idea is to create filter for PatchTable method, create logging to pubsub sink, use pubsub topic as the trigger of the cloud function.

Comment: I suggest that you post another question here in SO with the code you've tried so it can be reproducible. You can also upvote or accept the answer if you have been sufficiently helped: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)