# trigger function when new data are added or edited in bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, triggers

I was wondering if there would be an option to trigger a cloud function when new data are added or edited in bigquery.

I recognize there is another post on stack overflow (here is the link):
[Trigger cloud function when new data in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792976/trigger-cloud-function-when-new-data-in-bigquery) but there has been some updates in GCP in the last year.

Could someone please explain me (in a very simple way) the steps I have to follow?

Thank you in advance

Comment: There is no new feature in BigQuery and the previous answer is still the right one. The BigQuery team is working on a CDC like mechanism to trigger event on changes, but there is no ETA for now

Comment: Hi @fpisto,I have provided an answer.If my answer addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any option to trigger a cloud function when new data are added or edited in bigquery?  Currently bigquery does not support this feature so there is no direct solution for this. As a workaround you can consider these [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792976/trigger-cloud-function-when-new-data-in-bigquery) and [thread2](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/how-trigger-cloud-run-actions-bigquery-events).

However, there is a feature request filed for the same. You can vote for [this feature](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115569337) by clicking the `+1` and `*STAR*` mark to receive updates on it.