# Is there a way to stream change logs from BigQuery into an API?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a service that exposes an RPC interface. I want to stream any changes made in multiple BigQuery projects into our API, but I can't see anything like setting up a CDC pipeline similar to what exists for Postgres.

Looking up CDC or streaming APIs only leads me to a write/read stream API but not about change logs that happen in a BQ project but instead reading rows. And CDC leads to the write API which is about streaming in changes to BigQuery but nothing about streaming the changes out of BigQuery.

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77132557/) help you?